# JasperReport: Parse Error at line 2 column 487,Document root element "jasperReport", must match DOCTYPE root "null"

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am trying to make pdf from jrxml file using java code,but it gives me following error:

```
SEVERE: Parse Error at line 2 column 487: Document root element "jasperReport", must match DOCTYPE root "null".
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 487; Document root element "jasperReport", must match DOCTYPE root "null".
......
```

My code:Main Class:

```
    public class MainClass_Dummy {
public static JasperDesign jasperDesign;
public static JasperPrint jasperPrint;
public static JasperReport jasperReport;
public static String filename = "D://ReceiptReport.jrxml";
public static String outputreport = "D://test_jasper.pdf";
static JRBeanCollectionDataSource jrBeanCollectionDataSource;
public MainClass_Dummy(){
try{
        System.out.println("Loading a jrxml file..");
        FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File(filename));
        jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(input); 
        jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);
        jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, null, jrBeanCollectionDataSource);
        Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("D:/ReceiptReport.pdf"));
        }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
        }
public static void main(String[] args) {
            Dummy_MainClass dm = new Dummy_MainClass();
            new MainClass_Dummy();  }
    }
```

It creates jrxml successfully and it works fine in ireport 5.5.0,but it gives error when i run it in eclipse,Please any one have solution then tell me.

Regards.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Document root element "jasperReport", must match DOCTYPE root "null"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21179122/document-root-element-jasperreport-must-match-doctype-root-null)

Comment: You need to check you version of your jasper report. version of jasper report and ireport should be same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of different version of jar files,i just changed old jar files and add current versions jar that is 5.5.0 version and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

1. It maybe caused by version confict in your ireport  and jar file available in your project library . Copy the same  jasper.jar file you use in your ireport designer and add it to your project.
2. It is not a good idea to load the **.JRXML** file in your program. You can compile it first in your ireport IDE and just load the compiled file .JASPER as follow

   `jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport( new FileInputStream(pathtoReport),  parameters, connection);`

Comment: i used jaspersoft ireport 5.5.0 tool,please tell me from where i have to copy that jasper.jar.

Comment: i am trying to make this report from java code.and i am using jasperreport 5.5.0.jar

Comment: In windows it is located under C:\Program Files\Jaspersoft\iReport-5.x.x\ireport\modules\ext

Comment: @soulemanemoumie `It is not a good idea to load the .JRXML file in your program` - Why it is not a good idea?

Comment: It is not efficient because each time you run the program it will first compile the .jxxml to .jasper first before converting it to PDF. That step is unnecessary and time consuming, and for a small report there not problem but for a large report on web app in can become an issue.

Comment: Direct call of .jasper is faster and more portable over different versions of jasperreport.